# In python-mode plugin NameError: name 'pymode' is not defined

Tags: python, vim, python-mode

I have just installed the python-mode plugin by vundle

```
deal with /home/lucas/.vim/autoload/pymode/doc.vim gets error:
line 3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pymode'
[Pymode]: error: No name/symbol under cursor!
```

this is my first time to use this plugin, does this mean there are some mistakes with installing the python-mode plugin?

Comment: Did you take a look at their troubleshooting? https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: @ MichaelMMeskhi vim -i NONE -u <path_to_pymode>/debugvimrc.vim and I open a blank file ,then .. it says reproduce the error and submit the debug file, which I cannot get its meaning

Comment: Okay let me try install this and see if I get it to work. Just tell me the purpose of you using pymode?

Comment: @ MichaelMMeskhi   I want to  find a better way to  run python code and get the debug message in a split window,  other than only `!python %`  to run python . I try to use quickfix window by `:make` but it gives me an error says cannot find the make file , so I try to install this plugin to help...

Comment: Also found this assuming you installed `pymode` https://vimawesome.com/plugin/python-mode

Comment: This worked for me https://realpython.com/blog/python/vim-and-python-a-match-made-in-heaven/

Comment: @ MichaelMMeskhi `vimawesome.com/plugin/python-mode ` is the same with the docs in github of python-mode,.... ` realpython.com/blog/python/` my vim also follow these steps to configure, but this tutorial doesn't give any content about how to run and see the result of python file